# Using correct regex in xslt 2.0

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I've been stuck using the correct regex. I need to tokenize each data per keys along with there values. In my example below,

Sample File:

```
<Rec>
   <Data>/CHG1/EUR1000,00/EXCH/0,10/CPRP/Payment Code 1</Data>
   <Data>/CHG1/EUR1000,00/EXCH/0,10/CPRP/Payment Code 1</Data>
   <Data>/CHG3/EUR3000,00/PURP//CD/Payment Code 3</Data>
   <Data>/CHG5/EUR5000,00/PURP//PRTRY/Payment Code 5</Data>
   <Data>/ORIG//CSID/EUR7000,00/BENM//ID/Payment Code 7</Data>
</Rec>
```

The keys with '//' in the middle is considered as 1 key. I need to generate the output like this:

```
<Data>
   <Group>
      <Token>/CHG1/EUR1000,00</Token>
      <Token>/EXCH/0,10</Token>
      <Token>/CPRP/Payment Code 1</Token>
   </Group>
   <Group>
      <Token>/CHG3/EUR3000,00</Token>
      <Token>/PURP//CD/Payment Code 3</Token>
   </Group>
   <Group>
      <Token>/CHG5/EUR5000,00</Token>
      <Token>/PURP//PRTRY/Payment Code 5</Token>
   </Group>
   <Group>
      <Token>/ORIG//CSID/EUR7000,00</Token>
      <Token>/BENM//ID/Payment Code 7</Token>
   </Group>
</Data>
```

But, my generated output is like this:

```
<Data>
   <Group>
      <Token>/CHG1/</Token>
      <Token>/EXCH/</Token>
      <Token>/CPRP/</Token>
   </Group>
   <Group>
      <Token>/CHG3/</Token>
      <Token>/PURP//CD/</Token>
   </Group>
   <Group>
      <Token>/CHG5/</Token>
      <Token>/PURP//PRTRY/</Token>
   </Group>
   <Group>
      <Token>/ORIG//CSID/</Token>
      <Token>/BENM//ID/</Token>
   </Group>
</Data>
```

Here is my XSLT that I've been using:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[boolean(normalize-space())]|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="Data">
    <xsl:for-each select=".">
        <Group>
            <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="\/[A-Z]+[0-9]?\/(\/(CD|PRTRY|MARF|ID|CSID|NAME|RID)\/)?">
                <xsl:matching-substring>
                    <xsl:variable name="val" select="."/>
                    <Token>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$val"/>
                    </Token>
                </xsl:matching-substring>
            </xsl:analyze-string>
        </Group>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

There is something missing in my regex expression. Can anyone help me figure out? Thank you for your feedback.

Comment: What is the logic behind your expected output? It makes no sense to me. Shouldn't there be a token for every **pair** of key/value (as in your first group)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't make heads or tails of your expected output. I suspect the correct output should be actually something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Rec>
   <Group>
      <Token>CHG1/EUR1000,00</Token>
      <Token>EXCH/0,10</Token>
      <Token>CPRP/Payment Code 1</Token>
   </Group>
   <Group>
      <Token>CHG1/EUR1000,00</Token>
      <Token>EXCH/0,10</Token>
      <Token>CPRP/Payment Code 1</Token>
   </Group>
   <Group>
      <Token>CHG3/EUR3000,00</Token>
      <Token>PURP/</Token>
      <Token>CD/Payment Code 3</Token>
   </Group>
   <Group>
      <Token>CHG5/EUR5000,00</Token>
      <Token>PURP/</Token>
      <Token>PRTRY/Payment Code 5</Token>
   </Group>
   <Group>
      <Token>ORIG/</Token>
      <Token>CSID/EUR7000,00</Token>
      <Token>BENM/</Token>
      <Token>ID/Payment Code 7</Token>
   </Group>
</Rec>
```

If so, I would suggest you change your approach and try:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Data">
    <xsl:variable name="t" select="tokenize(., '/')" />
    <Group>
        <xsl:for-each select="$t[position() mod 2 = 0]">
            <xsl:variable name="i" select="index-of($t, .)"/>
            <Token>
                <xsl:value-of select="." />
                <xsl:text>/</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="$t[$i + 1]" />
            </Token>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </Group>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Demo: http://xsltransform.net/93dEHGr

---

Or even simpler:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Data">
    <Group>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="tokenize(., '/')" group-by="position() idiv 2">
            <Token>
                <xsl:value-of select="current-group()" separator="/"/>
            </Token>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </Group>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Demo: http://xsltransform.net/93dEHGr/2

---

### Added:

> Actually, the keys with 2 '//' in the middle is considered as 1 key.

Well, then let's take the `//` strings out of the game before doing the tokenizing, and restore them at the end:

```
<xsl:template match="Data">
    <Group>
        <xsl:for-each-group  select="tokenize(replace(., '//', '§§§'), '/')" group-by="position() idiv 2">
            <Token>
                <xsl:value-of select="replace(string-join(current-group(), '/'), '§§§', '//')" />
            </Token>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </Group>
</xsl:template>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Rec>
   <Group>
      <Token/>
      <Token>CHG1/EUR1000,00</Token>
      <Token>EXCH/0,10</Token>
      <Token>CPRP/Payment Code 1</Token>
   </Group>
   <Group>
      <Token/>
      <Token>CHG1/EUR1000,00</Token>
      <Token>EXCH/0,10</Token>
      <Token>CPRP/Payment Code 1</Token>
   </Group>
   <Group>
      <Token/>
      <Token>CHG3/EUR3000,00</Token>
      <Token>PURP//CD/Payment Code 3</Token>
   </Group>
   <Group>
      <Token/>
      <Token>CHG5/EUR5000,00</Token>
      <Token>PURP//PRTRY/Payment Code 5</Token>
   </Group>
   <Group>
      <Token/>
      <Token>ORIG//CSID/EUR7000,00</Token>
      <Token>BENM//ID/Payment Code 7</Token>
   </Group>
</Rec>
```

http://xsltransform.net/93dEHGr/4

Comment: Thanks!Actually, the keys with 2 '//' in the middle is considered as 1 key. For example, the /PURP//PRTRY/, /ORIG//CSID/.

Comment: @YoonaMay See the addition to my answer. Note that you can replace the separators, if you like. I am not sure what your target application is, but having both `/` and `//` in different roles is very  inconvenient. Ideally, the key and the value would be in separate nodes.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this with tokenize in xslt 2.0

```
        <xsl:template match="Rec">
        <Data>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </Data>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Data">
            <Group>
                <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(., '0/')">
                    <Token>
                        <xsl:if test="position() ne 1">
                            <xsl:text>/</xsl:text>
                        </xsl:if>
                        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                        <xsl:if test="position() ne last()">
                            <xsl:text>0</xsl:text>
                        </xsl:if>
                    </Token>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </Group>
    </xsl:template>
```